# How can I use `psutils` to imposition 16 A7 pages onto the front and back of a A4 sheet so it will fold into a booklet?

Tags: printing, postscript

I want to use [`psutils`](http://knackered.org/angus/psutils/) to [imposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imposition) 16 A7 pages onto one A4 paper, so that it can be folded three times to create a booklet (that has to be cut of course). The booklet will be in A7 format and have 16 pages.

**How can I do this with `psutils`?**

---

A clue: [Arranging a PostScript Document in a Booklet](http://www.dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_25.html#SEC371)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ps document with 16 A7 pages, you can imposition the folder with the following command:

```
pstops -pa4 '16:0R(0,0.25h)+15R(0,0.5h)+12R(0,0.75h)+3R(0,1h)+7L(1w,0)+8L(1w,0.25h)+11L(1w,0.5h)+4L(1w,0.75h),2L(1w,0.75h)+13L(1w,0.5h)+14L(1w,0.25h)+1L(1w,0)+5R(0,1h)+10R(0,0.75h)+9R(0,0.5h)+6R(0,0.25h)' input.ps output.ps
```

[image]

Some notes on the command:

`16:` Set the *modulo* to 16 pages (*pageno*). A modulo is the array of pages that we will work with. If the original document would have had 32 pages it would in our case consist of two modulos, and for each of them the same rearranging pattern would be used.
he

`0` After specifying the number of pagenos in the modulo, we choose which pageno to work with. We start out with pageno 0, that is page 1 of the original ps file.

`R` Rotate 90° to the right.

`L` Rotate 90° to the right.

`U` Turn upside down (rotate 180°).

All transformations are done relative to the lower left corner of the pageno in question.

`(0,0.25h)` Inside the parenthesis we specify if we want to move the pageno. `0.25h` means 0.25 × *page height*.

---

Source: [Making an unopened A7 booklet from a folded A4 sheet](https://blog.a-x.name/2018/04/19/making-an-unopened-a7-booklet-from-a-folded-a4-sheet/#more-13)